# file upload with axioso is showing undefined in multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

I am trying to upload file using react and axios to node backend using multer.

when i use form as :

```
<form  action = '/article/add' method="POST"  className = {adminStyle.add_article_form} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type='text' className={adminStyle.add_article_input_title} autoComplete = 'off' name='title' placeholder='Title' value = {state.title} onChange={changeHandler}/>
                        <select name='category' value = {state.category} onChange={changeHandler}>
                            {options}
                        </select>
                        <input  type="file" name='thumbnail' className={adminStyle.add_article_input_file} onChange={changeFileHandler}/>
                        <textarea  type = 'text' name='body' className={adminStyle.add_article_textarea}  rows='30' cols='100' value = {state.body} onChange={changeHandler}></textarea>
                        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

it works fine but when using axios the file is undefined:

I used axios as:

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
        title: '',
        category: 'Choose one',
        body: '',
        thumbnail: ''

    })
const changeFileHandler = (e) => {
        setState({ thumbnail: e.target.files[0] })
    }
const postArticle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('thumbnail', state.thumbnail)
        axios.post('/article/add', state,config).then(data => console.log(data))
    }

<form  onSubmit={postArticle}  className = {adminStyle.add_article_form} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type='text' className={adminStyle.add_article_input_title} autoComplete = 'off' name='title' placeholder='Title' value = {state.title} onChange={changeHandler}/>
                        <select name='category' value = {state.category} onChange={changeHandler}>
                            {options}
                        </select>
                        <input  type="file" name='thumbnail' className={adminStyle.add_article_input_file} onChange={changeFileHandler}/>
                        <textarea  type = 'text' name='body' className={adminStyle.add_article_textarea}  rows='30' cols='100' value = {state.body} onChange={changeHandler}></textarea>
                        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

My backend is as follow:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '..', '../public/uploads'),
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
      cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
  });
  function checkFileType(file, cb){
    // Allowed extension name
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    // Check ext
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  
    if(mimetype && extname){
      return cb(null,true);
    } else {
      cb('Error: Images Only!');
    }
  }

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fileSize: 1000000},
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
      checkFileType(file, cb);
    }
  }).single('thumbnail')

router.post('/add',(req, res)=>{
    upload(req,res, (err) => {
        console.log(req.file)
    })
});
```

can anyone help me with this? I am really stuck. I need to upload the image in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `state` and not `formData` as the `body` of the `request`. You should change this line:

```
axios.post('/article/add', state,config).then(data => console.log(data))
```

with this line:

```
axios.post('/article/add', formData ,config).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: let config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
      };

Comment: I updated my answer. Check if that works for you.

Comment: Consider approving my answer if it helps you.